# How to turn off Fn key on IBM T60 programmatically

Tags: windows-7, thinkpad, fn-key

I have some problems with the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key on my `IBM T60`. I'm using Windows 7.

The <kbd>Fn</kbd> key remains pressed all the time, so I want to turn it off programmatically.

Please tell me how I can do this?

Comment: What do you mean by turn it off? Are you trying to toggle something?

Comment: A screwdriver and some force?

Comment: Can you Disable it from BIOS ? I can disable/enable my Fn button from BIOS..

Comment: How????????????

Comment: @JasonPaddle how can i do this??

Comment: @DawoodAbbasi can you check in your Bios for option like on this picture http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/836/c02035200.jpg/

Answer (score 0):

Open an administrator command-prompt and use the following command<sup>[[1]](http://laptoprepair.ca/news/13186/3.html)</sup>:

```
PS2 FNS D
```

Comment: not working..... :(